# Add watermark/logo to Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

I've been looking through docs and other SO posts, but it seems this hasn't been asked before.

Is there any way to add a watermark or logo to a chart made with Chart.js?

I need this mainly for when people download the chart as an image, I don't care too much whether it shows up on my website or not, as long as it's there when the user downloads it.

Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: How do you make it accessible for a download? Do you use `toDataUrl()`? The way to go would probably be to manually add a watermark after you generated it with Chart.js.

Comment: `canvas {
   background-image: url(imageurl);
}` by this you can add image. 
How you generate image?

Comment: sorry everyone and thanks a lot for your help! I've managed to find a js plugin that's very old but it seems to do exactly what I need :) Sorry for wasting your time! https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-watermark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry for finding an answer myself minutes after posting the question, but for the life of me I couldn't find this before :(

This Chart.js plugin will do exactly that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-watermark

```js
options: {

      watermark: {

          image: "//imgurlhere.jpg",
          x: 20,
          y: 10,
          width: 53,
          height: 60,
          opacity: 0.25,
          alignX: "left",
          alignY: "top",
          alignToChartArea: true,
          position: "back"

      },

}
```

Comment: do not work with latest ChartJs version.

Comment: chartjs-plugin-watermark 2.0.0 has been released and works with Chart.js 3 and 4: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-watermark/v/2.0.0